# Cannot find module (Error: Cannot find module './models/campground')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

this is my code

```
var express     = require("express"),
app         = express(),
bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
mongoose    = require("mongoose"),
Campground  = require("./models/campground"),
Comment     = require("./models/comment"),
seedDB      = require("./seeds")
```

[this are my file's tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBgO7.png)
and when i run the above code, i get this error,
Error: Cannot find module './models/campground'
Require stack:

```
 - /workspace/webDevBootcamp/yelpcamp/v4/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/webDevBootcamp/yelpcamp/v4/app.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/workspace/webDevBootcamp/yelpcamp/v4/app.js' ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is the file name that you have written. In the screenshot that you have provided the file name is `Campgorund` and you have tried to import `campground`. There is no other issue. Please fix that and your code will start to work properly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Campground  = require("./models/campground"),
```

By

```
Campground  = require("./models/campgorund"),
```

Or change the filename "campgorund.js" to "campground.js".
:)

Comment: Please explain the difference between those two inline codes. 

Replace
Campground  = require("./models/campground"), by Campground  = require("./models/campgorund"),

Comment: In the first line, it's requiring a file that doesn't exist. "campground". Because the file is called "campgorund"

In the second one the filename is correct